# How to React-Table Pop Up in the cell?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, popup, react-table

How do I add a button in a table and click on it to open a Pop Up?

```
      {
       Header: 'test', 
       accessor: 'test', 
       headerClassName: 'wordwrap'
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give function what return react component to accessor:

```
  {
     Header: 'test', 
     accessor: item => <Button onClick={() => this.handleClick(item.id)} />, 
     headerClassName: 'wordwrap'
  },
```